# Send images from sdcard to server using multipart entry

Tags: android, image, multipart

I am making an android app in which i am sending image to server from  /mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20110922_124932.jpg to serverthrough multipart request .. Can anybody help me out.... 
Any help will be appreciated..
Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple example of a multipart post that I use to send images to a server:

```
public void MultipartPost(){
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(url);
//Set Credentials
    String auth = User + ":" + Pass;
    byte[] bytes = auth.getBytes();
    postRequest.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + new String(Base64.encodeBytes(bytes)));


    try {


        MultipartEntity mpC = new MultipartEntity();

        //Create stringbody for the filename
    StringBody sbPicID = new StringBody("123.jpg");

        //get a file reference from the image on the SD card
    File fle = new File("full path to the file");

        //create a filebody from the file
    FileBody fb = new FileBody(fle);

    //Add the file name and filebody to the Multipart Entitiy
    mpC.addPart("myImage", sbPicID);
    mpC.addPart("myImage", fb);

       //Set the entitiy of the post request to your Multipart
        postRequest.setEntity(mpC);

       HttpResponse res;

   //execute the post request
       Log.d(TAG,"Starting Send...");
   res = httpClient.execute(postRequest);
   Log.d(TAG, res.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase());
   Log.d(TAG, res.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
   res.getEntity().getContent().close();
   Log.d(TAG,"After Close");

   } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
   }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

See the accepted answer of [this question here][1] that I answered last week. It's very similar to the answer above but also includes some sample PHP code to get the image.

[JSON and upload image to server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7433452/json-and-upload-image-to-server/7435234#comment-9005536)